# Sharing Printer to Windows Client

Tags: windows, printing, samba

My Desktop is running Ubuntu 14.04 with a Canon MP490 printer connected. I am wanting to share the printer to a Gateway laptop running Windows 7.

The printer prints fine from the desktop. The laptop was able to discover the printer and I installed the drivers. Everything looks normal and like it should work. When I try to print from the laptop it doesn't work. It looks like it is sending the job to the printer then nothing happens.

I have been searching Google but have not come across an answer that has worked. I am a bit lost at this point.

Here is what my samba configuration looks like:

```
[global]
workgroup = sandman
server string = UbuntuDesktop
netbios name = srvr1
security = share
map to guest = bad user
name resolve order = bcast host
dns proxy = no
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
; encrypt passwords = yes
guest ok = yes
; guest account = nobody
printcap name = cups
printing = cups

[Videos]
comment = Videos and Movies
path = /home/harvey/Videos
writeable = yes
; browseable = yes
guest ok = yes

[Public]
comment = Public folder.
path = /home/harvey/Public
writeable = yes
; browseable = yes
guest ok = yes

[Pictures]
comment = Photos
path = /home/harvey/Pictures
writeable = yes
; browseable = yes
guest ok = yes

[Music]
comment = Music
path = /home/harvey/Music
writeable = yes
; browseable = yes
guest ok = yes

[printers]
browseable = yes
printable = yes
public = yes
create mode = 0700
guest only = yes
use client driver = yes
guest account = smbprint
path = /home/smbprint
```

Comment: If it's a Windows driver issue, try changing "use client drivers" to "no".

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of problems trying to share a Canon printer attached to my Ubuntu desktop, similar to what you stated.  Jobs look like they print, but never did.  The easiest solution was to install Google Chrome and use its cloud printer feature.  Then on the Windows side there was a Google Cloud printer app.  Also worked well for printing from my Android devices.  In my smb.conf file, I commented out all references to printers so they would not show up on the Windows PCs.